# I'd like to display the price label at the end of the right screen in the Auto Fib Retention Script, which is a trading view built-in

Tags: pine-script

In the TradingView built-in script, Auto Fib Retention Script, I'd like to pin the label next to the price line at the right end of the screen. scripted:

```
x_draw_label (price, txt, txtColor) => 
    x = labelsPosition == "Left" ? line.get_x1(lineLast) : line.get_x2(lineLast)
```

When you select the right side of the label position, only the maximum `line.get_x2(lineLast)` is moved.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to fix it next to the price line at the end of the right screen.

```
//@version=4
study("Auto Fib Retracement", overlay=true)

// pivots threshold
threshold_multiplier = input(title="Deviation", type=input.float, defval=3, minval=0)
dev_threshold = atr(10) / close * 100 * threshold_multiplier

depth = input(title="Depth", type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1)
var extendLeft = input(false, "Extend Lines Left")
var extendRight = input(true, "Extend Lines Right")

var extending = extend.none
if extendLeft and extendRight
    extending := extend.both
if extendLeft and not extendRight 
    extending := extend.left
if not extendLeft and extendRight
    extending := extend.right

reverse = input(false, "Reverse")
prices = input(true, "Prices")
levels = input(true, "Levels")
levelsFormat = input("Values", "Levels Format", options = ["Values", "Percent"])
labelsPosition = input("Left", "Labels Position", options = ["Left", "Right"])

var line lineLast = na
var int iLast = 0
var int iPrev = 0
var float pLast = 0
var isHighLast = false // otherwise the last pivot is a low pivot

pivots(src, length, isHigh) => 
    l2 = length * 2 
    c = nz(src[length])
    ok = true
    for i = 0 to l2
        if isHigh and src[i] > c
            ok := false

        if not isHigh and src[i] < c
            ok := false
    if ok
        [bar_index[length], c]
    else
        [int(na), float(na)]
[iH, pH] = pivots(high, depth / 2, true)
[iL, pL] = pivots(low, depth / 2, false)

calc_dev(base_price, price) =>
    100 * (price - base_price) / price

pivotFound(dev, isHigh, index, price) => 
    if isHighLast == isHigh and not na(lineLast)
        // same direction
        if isHighLast ? price > pLast : price < pLast
            line.set_xy2(lineLast, index, price)
            [lineLast, isHighLast]
        else
            [line(na), bool(na)]
    else // reverse the direction (or create the very first line)
        if abs(dev) > dev_threshold
            // price move is significant
            id = line.new(iLast, pLast, index, price, color=color.gray, width=1, style=line.style_dashed)
            [id, isHigh]
        else
            [line(na), bool(na)]

if not na(iH)
    dev = calc_dev(pLast, pH)
    [id, isHigh] = pivotFound(dev, true, iH, pH)
    if not na(id)
        if id != lineLast
            line.delete(lineLast)
        lineLast := id
        isHighLast := isHigh
        iPrev := iLast
        iLast := iH
        pLast := pH
else
    if not na(iL)
        dev = calc_dev(pLast, pL)
        [id, isHigh] = pivotFound(dev, false, iL, pL)
        if not na(id)
            if id != lineLast
                line.delete(lineLast)
            lineLast := id
            isHighLast := isHigh
            iPrev := iLast
            iLast := iL
           pLast := pL

_draw_line(price, col) =>
    var id = line.new(iLast, price, bar_index, price, color=col, width=1, extend=extending)
    if not na(lineLast)
        line.set_xy1(id, line.get_x1(lineLast), price)
        line.set_xy2(id, line.get_x2(lineLast), price)


****_draw_label(price, txt, txtColor) => 
    x = labelsPosition == "Left" ? line.get_x1(lineLast) : line.get_x2(lineLast)
    var id = label.new(x=x, y=price, text=txt, textcolor=txtColor, style=label.style_none)
    label.set_xy(id, x, price)
    label.set_text(id, txt)
    label.set_textcolor(id, txtColor)****

_wrap(txt) =>
    "(" + tostring(txt, "#.##") + ")"

_label_txt(level, price) =>
    l = levelsFormat == "Values" ? tostring(level) : tostring(level * 100) + "%"
    (levels ? l : "") + (prices ? _wrap(price) : "")

sl1 = input(true, "0")
vall1 = 0.000

sl2 = input(true, "0.236")
vall2 = 0.236

sl3 = input(true, "0.382")
vall3 = 0.382

sl4 = input(true, "0.5")
vall4 = 0.5

sl5 = input(true, "0.618")
vall5 = 0.618

sl6 = input(true, "0.786")
vall6 = 0.786

sl7 = input(true, "1")
vall7 = 1

sl8 = input(true, "1.272")
vall8 = 1.272

sl9 = input(true, "1.414")
vall9 = 1.414

sl10 = input(true, "1.618")
vall10 = 1.618

_draw_retracement(startPrice, endPrice) =>
    iHL = startPrice > endPrice
    diff = (iHL ? -1 : 1) * abs(startPrice - endPrice)
    if sl1
        l1 = startPrice + diff * vall1
        _draw_line(l1, #808080)
        _draw_label(l1, _label_txt(vall1, l1), #808080)

    if sl2
        l2 = startPrice + diff * vall2
        _draw_line(l2, #a61c00)
        _draw_label(l2, _label_txt(vall2, l2), #a61c00)

    if sl3
        l3 = startPrice + diff * vall3
        _draw_line(l3, #95cc28)
        _draw_label(l3, _label_txt(vall3, l3), #95cc28)

    if sl4
        l4 = startPrice + diff * vall4
        _draw_line(l4, #28cc28)
        _draw_label(l4, _label_txt(vall4, l4), #28cc28)

    if sl5
        l5 = startPrice + diff * vall5
        _draw_line(l5, #28cc95)
        _draw_label(l5, _label_txt(vall5, l5), #28cc95)

    if sl6
        l6 = startPrice + diff * vall6
        _draw_line(l6, #2895cc)
        _draw_label(l6, _label_txt(vall6, l6), #2895cc)

    if sl7
        l7 = startPrice + diff * vall7
        _draw_line(l7, #808080)
        _draw_label(l7, _label_txt(vall7, l7), #808080)

    if sl8
        l8 = startPrice + diff * vall8
        _draw_line(l8, #82CA89)
        _draw_label(l8, _label_txt(vall8, l8), #82CA89)

    if sl9
        l9 = startPrice + diff * vall9
        _draw_line(l9, #F32C42)
        _draw_label(l9, _label_txt(vall9, l9), #F32C42)

    if sl10
        l10 = startPrice + diff * vall10
        _draw_line(l10, #2796ED)
        _draw_label(l10, _label_txt(vall10, l10), #2796ED)


p1 = reverse ? line.get_y1(lineLast) : pLast
p2 = reverse ? pLast : line.get_y1(lineLast)
_draw_retracement(p1, p2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
_draw_label(price, txt, txtColor) => 
    x = labelsPosition == "Left" ? line.get_x1(lineLast) : bar_index
    var id = label.new(x=x, y=price, text=txt, textcolor=txtColor, style=label.style_none)
    label.set_xy(id, x, price)
    label.set_text(id, txt)
    label.set_textcolor(id, txtColor)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It was very helpful.^^

By the way, can't I have it displayed on the right side of the Price Index instead of "bar_index"?

Comment: What do you mean by "right side of the Price Index"?

Comment: If you expand the Fibonacci, the price label is displayed next to the price scale on the right side of the screen. I want to move like this. I have attached the image. Please confirm.^^

Comment: No, that's not possible for now, because the only way labels can be positioned to the right of the last bar is by using a point in time, which will vary all the time as the chart moves. Scripts have no way to know how far to the right the price scale is.

Comment: hi^^
I left another inquiry at the address below, so could you please check it? Thank you very much :)      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62588280/inquiries-on-how-to-label-bar-when-mfi-or-rsi-hline-is-breakthrough