# Inquiries on how to label bar when MFI or RSI hline is breakthrough

Tags: pine-script

If MFI or RSI exceeds hline(80) or hline(20), I want to label the bar. Is there anyone who can tell me the script?
Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

An example

```
//@version=4
study("My Script",overlay=true)
length = input(14),src = input(close)
//----
mfi = mfi(src,length)
rsi = rsi(src,length)
cnd = crossover(mfi,80) or crossover(rsi,80) or crossover(mfi,20) or crossover(rsi,20)
plotshape(cnd ? close : na,location=location.belowbar,text="Text")
```

You could also use `label.new` within an `if` statement but `plotshape` might be more appropriate in your case.

Comment: Wow. Thank you.^^. Can I ask you through "if"?