# How to Label with text on a Plotted Horizontal Line

Tags: label, pine-script, horizontal-line

I am using TradingView - Pine Script v5. I have written a program that takes variable averages from previous days to plot straight horizontal levels for each day. I would like to label these lines respectively. Once the variables is set in the first moment of the day, it will stay like that until day close, so it a "constant", but am having difficulty identifying/setting "yloc" value. Is there a simple way to add a label to each of these lines?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[I'd like to display the price label at the end of the right screen in the Auto Fib Retention Script, which is a trading view built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363590/id-like-to-display-the-price-label-at-the-end-of-the-right-screen-in-the-auto-f)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).